# How to find same color bubbles in bubble shooter game - in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to create bubble shooter game like bubble saga.. But I cant see any tutorials or document to complete the game online.. Lot of tutorials are available for only place the bubbles.. But i want to know searching method to drop the same color bubbles and if any bubble are alone, its also want to be removed..

I tried and complete only place the bubbles..

```
    private function placeBubbles():void
    {
        var bubble:Bubble; // bubble movieclip load from library

        for(var i:uint = 0; i < _columns; i++)
        {
            for(var j:uint = 0; j < _rows; j++)
            {
                bubble = new Bubble();
                bubble.x = _startX + (_hexWidth * i + ( j % 2) * _hexWidth/2);
                bubble.y = _startY + (_hexHeight * j / 4 * 3);
                bubble.mouseChildren = false;
                bubble.name =String(i + j * _columns);
                bubble.txt.text = bubble.name;
                bubble.gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(Math.random()*bubble.totalFrames - 3))
                _container.addChild(bubble);
            }
        }
    }
```

Would feel helpful if someone give the code or tutorials.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a designated property on the bubble itself. Say, you can name a property `color`, design a meaning for it (indexed, most likely, and given you are using `gotoAndStop()` for a certain color, you'd better map it to current frame of the MC), and query just that property. An example:

```
... // your code for bubble creation
bubble.color=Math.ceil(Math.random()*bubble.totalFrames - 3);
bubble.gotoAndStop(bubble.color);
```

And then you query target bubble's `color` property to find matches in the nearby bubbles.

About searching for nearby bubbles - use a grid (two-dimensional array), fill it with bubbles as you place them, and query neighboring elements for matching color and occupation (if null, there's no bubble at this position, so don't query for color).